"Network error: software caused connection abort"
I am experiencing a persistent issue when using PuTTY. I can logon to my ubuntu server, but after 5 minutes the connection is terminated with the following message:
"network error: software caused connection abort."
I have attempted to diagnose the problem but have not been successful. How to resolve?
error

Start Putty
Click on “Connection”
On the section that says "Sending of null packets to keep session active", Changed it to 5 seconds.
How keepalives to prevent disconnection with Putty:
Some network routers and firewalls need to keep track of all connections through them. Usually, these firewalls will assume a connection is dead if no data is transferred in either direction after a certain time interval. This can cause PuTTY sessions to be unexpectedly closed by the firewall if no traffic is seen in the session for some time.
The keepalive option (‘Seconds between keepalives’) allows you to configure PuTTY to send data through the session at regular intervals, in a way that does not disrupt the actual terminal session. If you find your firewall is cutting idle connections off, you can try entering a non-zero value in this field. The value is measured in seconds; so, for example, if your firewall cuts connections off after ten minutes then you might want to enter 300 seconds (5 minutes) in the box.

thanks for answering but it also not work the previous troubleshooting steps didn't resolve my problem. again it gives the "network error: software cause connection abort" error. i try  to acces my server remotly with bitwise ssh client and remote desktop also but it also not working
